# How to run .exe file in Desktop for Windows using Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, desktop, os.system

I'm trying to run a .exe file written in Python by a click of a button located in Desktop. Need this to work on anyone's desktop so I tested below code but it's giving me errors:

Code:

```
import os

TestButton = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop', 'Test.exe')
os.system(TestButton)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\<myuser>\Desktop\Test.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

How can I call test.exe from this location Desktop/Test/test.exe. Looking forward to your assist. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show me the errors.

Comment: Use os.startfile(path_to_your_file)

Comment: @VandanRevanur, thanks for the suggestion. The path to my .exe is on the Desktop and I intend to compile my script for the users. Hardcoding the path under my username will result to an issue. I will try os.starfile once I get a chance. Thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  I can execute the "Test.exe" in my desktop using your code.  Is your `Test.exe` in the Desktop or inside a folder "Test" in the Desktop (since you have mentioned *"Desktop/Test/Test.exe"* in your question)?

Comment: hi@acw1668, yes the Test.exe is inside the Test folder in the Desktop.

Comment: Then try `TestButton = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], 'Desktop', 'Test', 'Test.exe')`.

Comment: @acw1668, thank you so much. it worked :) appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are posting pseudocode but `python.exe` is not valid variable, let alone argument

```py
import os

python_exe = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop', 'python.exe')
os.system(python_exe)
```

Edit:
Try

```py
os.system(f'"{TestButton}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Those whitespaces can really be a bother. Try os.chdir('C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/') followed by relative paths for os.system, subprocess methods, or whatever...

If best-effort attempts to bypass the whitespaces-in-path hurdle keep failing, then my next best suggestion is to avoid having blanks in your crucial paths. Couldn't you make a blanks-less directory, copy the crucial .exe file there, and try that? Are those havoc-wrecking space absolutely essential to your well-being...?