# "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.", how do i resolve this in python?

Tags: python, desktop, os.system

This is related to my question on how to run a .exe file located in Desktop. Tried the suggested code but I'm having below error message. I would really appreciate if someone can help me resolve this issue. Thank you so much.

Code:

```
import os

TestButton = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop', 'Test.exe')
os.system(f'"{TestButton}"')
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\<myuser>\Desktop\Test.exe' is not recognized as an internal or   
external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Related Question:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305774/how-to-run-exe-file-in-desktop-for-windows-using-python
```

Comment: Use os.startfile(path_to_your_file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run .exe file in Desktop for Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305774/how-to-run-exe-file-in-desktop-for-windows-using-python)

Comment: is <myuser> a valid value for a path? what's the value of `TestButton`?

Comment: hi @Kulasangar, <myuser> could be anyone’s user. The value of the TestButton should be C:\Users\<myuser>\Desktop\Test.exe'